# Ускорение insert-ов в базу MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, оптимизация, mariadb

Всем привет, работаю с добавлением большого объема данных в таблицу БД MariaDB. Объемы в районе 500 тыс - 1 млн. Как можно ускорить процесс добавления записей? На данный момент использую insert ignore и добавляю пачками по 1000 записей. Конечно быстрее чем если по одной, но все равно нужны большие скорости добавления. Подскажите что можно сделать в данной ситуации.
Перепутал таблицу, вот верная:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `analyzer_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `analyzer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `resource` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNKEYS` (`analyzer_id`,`item_id`),
  KEY `analyzer_id` (`analyzer_id`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17690244 ;
```

Comment: С MariaDB не работал, но поверхностное гугление показывает, что у неё есть возможность вставки из файла. Ну и остальные пункты здесь посмотрите https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/

Comment: Если загрузка разовая, удалите лишние индексы. Оставьте только тот, который обеспечивает уникальность ignore. После заливки данных постройте их опять.

Comment: Это разовая операция? Что является источником данных?

Comment: MaxU, это не разова операция. Это постоянная операция. Производится поиск, потом добавление результатов поиска в таблицу

Comment: @Baurzhan, “LOAD DATA” - уже пробовали?

Comment: @MaxU вот сейчас пробую, только ошибка "The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version". Подскажите как на клиенте включить разрешение, так как на сервере вроде разрешение стоит на эту команду

Comment: @Baurzhan, используйте “load data local” если загружаете данные с клиента, а не с сервера MariaDB

Comment: Поиск производится из этой же базы данных? Попробуйте вместо INSERT ... VALUES использовать синтаксис INSERT ... SELECT

Comment: @MaxU, на клиенте для разрешения данной команды вставил параметр local_infile = 1 в файле my.cnf, перезапустил сервер, попробовал, не помогло. По прежнему выходит ошибка "the used command is not allowed with this mariadb version". Подскажите что можно сделать

Comment: если вы активно удаляете/добавляете, такими объёмами - сносите с таблицы все индексы, кроме основного. увы - они замедляют вам все процессы, а не ускоряют. 
 проверьте по статистие какое соотношение selectов к insert/updateам. если оно существенно в пользу insert/update - удаляйте индексы однозначно.